# Android - getting null response in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I wrote a XMLParser myself to get a certain string from a xml, everything works fine when testing it in a Java application, but when doing it in android it returns a null value. I researched and found out that I will need to use AsyncTask in order to call the web service in a separate thread. I did and I still get a null value. Here is the code

```
 private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

          private String resp;

          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           //publishProgress("Sleeping..."); // Calls onProgressUpdate()
            XmlParser getP = new XmlParser();
            resp = getP.getClo();
           return resp;
          }
          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

           Log.d("Verify: ", "" + result);    
          }
}
```

I execute this by making an OnClick on a dialog interface :
new AsyncTaskRunner().execute();
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

below piece of code obviously return null.

```
 XmlParser getP = new XmlParser();
        resp = getP.getClo();
       return resp;
```

since `XmlParser getP = new XmlParser();` object creation happening, and your trying to access threr only with no value set that object

Comment: what? that does not make any sense. the class XmlPrser has eveyrthing it needs. getCLo() method returns a string. When testing it out of android it works fine.

Comment: Post Xml parsor class

Answer (score 0):

In your statement, `XmlParser getP = new XmlParser();` you have only created an XmlParser, you have yet to set it to a value. It is effectively useless until you do something with it. for more information on the XmlParser see this documentation - http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlParser.html

Comment: oh no no, XmlParser is a class I implemented myself, it just happened to be called the same. XmlParser works fine, is something in android. When I put the same code on a java app, it works perfectly, but not on android.

Comment: Be careful naming classes that you create, it could get very confusing if you had not mentioned that you created that. You should give your class a different name.

Comment: I had no idea XmlParser was an already famous implemented class lol, but sure I will keep it on mind. The think is that I created a java app to test that getClo works, and it wors way too fine, something is going on that android is not letting me call the webservice. I even did the internet permission in the manifest and as fas as I know the way to do a call to a web service is via an asynctask. I have no idea how to fix this. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Can you include the error and/or the logcat output?

Comment: No error, im just getting back the result as null. it should be not null